Why are we not sinless until our physical body dies?
Christianity has always opposed any religion that considered the soul purer or holier by nature than the body, as some eastern religions or Gnosticism did.  At the same time Christianity through new birth introduced two natures in a man, at war with each other calling, one the flesh and the other the Spirit. (Gal 5:17)
Most biblical commentators I have read make sure it is understood that the term ‘flesh’ in scripture is not just referring to the physical body but by the word ‘flesh’ it means the whole evil nature, soul and body, to make sure the idea of a false Gnostic conflict between soul and body is avoided.
To muddy the waters slightly, there is a general admission through the Lords prayer that Christians still need to pray daily: give us this day our daily bread and forgive us our sins as we forgive those who sin against us. There may be some that think they might not sin a whole day but most Christians, at least the ones I have met, would agree with the concept that they are still very much guilty of daily sins against God’s perfect law after conversion. Only that by the blood of Christ are they cleansed and forgiven by their confession. But even those that believe in some kind of Christian perfectionism and imagine to be sinless for several days or longer would still understand that they frequently sin, just as James says in James 3:2.
I personally feel I perpetually fall short of obeying the Law fully as I doubt I have ever loved God more than half as much as I ought to. But that is just my own persuasion along with several famous Protestants mind you.
On the other hand, there is a general belief that after we die physically, that we will never sin again.
In summary, common Christian beliefs. While in the body:
1 John 1:8-9 (ESV)

[8] If we say we have no sin, we deceive ourselves, and the truth is
not in us. [9] If we confess our sins, he is faithful and just to
forgive us our sins and to cleanse us from all unrighteousness.

After we die, in heaven
Revelation 21:4

[4] He will wipe away every tear from their eyes, and death shall be
no more, neither shall there be mourning, nor crying, nor pain
anymore, for the former things have passed away.”

So the question is: if the word ‘flesh’ is not highly linked to the physical body, why is this the case (without promoting any kind eastern religious or gnostic ideas) that, while we live in the physical body, we can’t avoid sin and after our soul leaves the body into heaven (or rather with a new body) we are sinless forever? Why does this shift in imperfect-to-perfect, occur, exactly when the physical body dies?

I think Romans 7 is relevant and also Philippians 3:21 Who shall change our vile body, that it may be fashioned like unto his glorious body. Are you referring to sin itself being present in flesh (unavoidably after Adam's transgression) or are you referring to being under its power (which we ought not to be if we are dead and risen with Christ in union with him and publicly declared so in our baptism) ? Up-voted +1.

@Nigel -  thanks. I  am referring to why? when the body dies we no longer sin as a question ,for others to attempt a formulated answer.  In my own mind ,  without sources but mere opinion, the main connection must be related to that the physical body is still sinful until our baptism if fully completed in our own physical death and that this must be why when, even though our ‘inner man’ that has undergone baptism already,  making us  ‘slaves to righteousness’ and therefore ‘cannot sin’ , yet there is yet still sin in our lives.and that makes us say ‘forgive us’ until the body is destroyed.

Putting the doctrine of Gnosticism to one side, it seems to me helpful to have a look at what sin actually is, as I think that reveals the answer to your question. We know that Jesus was completely sinless and perfect in His walk on this earth, and He fulfilled everything that He came to do. So what was it He came to do?
John 6:35-40 says,
'And Jesus said to them, “I am the bread of life. He who comes to Me shall never hunger, and he who believes in Me shall never thirst. But I said to you that you have seen Me and yet do not believe. All that the Father gives Me will come to Me, and the one who comes to Me I will by no means cast out. For I have come down from heaven, not to do My own will, but the will of Him who sent Me. This is the will of the Father who sent Me, that of all He has given Me I should lose nothing, but should raise it up at the last day. And this is the will of Him who sent Me, that everyone who sees the Son and believes in Him may have everlasting life; and I will raise him up at the last day.”'
So if you were to strip back the work of Jesus to one command, one instruction that He obeyed to the letter, it would be that He did the will of His Father who sent Him, and did so perfectly. And it was through doing the will of His Father that He performed all of the miracles He did, that He spent regular time in communion with His Father, that He held back when Lazarus got sick, and that He went to the cross to pay the penalty for sin. In fact, even the messages He spoke and the teaching He shared was from the Father, 'For I have not spoken on My own authority; but the Father who sent Me gave Me a command, what I should say and what I should speak.' (John 12:49)
However, we also know from scripture that Jesus had flesh, and was fully human as well as fully God. We also know that He underwent temptation (although He never gave in to temptation), especially when he was lead into the wilderness. We also know that He didn't always find being obedient to the Father easy, and we get a particularly potent picture of that in the garden of Gethsemane just before His arrest. So we therefore know that the flesh is not inherently sinful because otherwise Jesus would have had sin, which He did not. It is also worth mentioning that our flesh was created by God with His own hands, and He did not create us to be evil.
But Paul is pretty clear in Romans 7 that sin is at the very least very closely related to the flesh, or at least our experience of sin is very closely related to the flesh, and I think that is the first clue. If you wind right back to Genesis, the very first sin was one of disobedience by Adam and Eve, which is the second clue.
The third and final clue to unlock what sin is comes in Romans 7 again, this time verses 21-25, specifically verse 25, 'I find then a law, that evil is present with me, the one who wills to do good. For I delight in the law of God according to the inward man. But I see another law in my members, warring against the law of my mind, and bringing me into captivity to the law of sin which is in my members. O wretched man that I am! Who will deliver me from this body of death? I thank God—through Jesus Christ our Lord! So then, with the mind I myself serve the law of God, but with the flesh the law of sin.'
So then, to put it simply, sin is serving another law, a law that is not God. Jesus was sinless because He was perfectly obedient to the will of the Father, and sin first came in (and by sin, death) because of the disobedience of Adam and Eve to the will of God. So sin is, in simple terms, disobedience to the will of God. And in unlocking that, we also unlock why it is that we cannot be without sin on this side of death.
To wind back to Adam and Eve again, when they were in the garden and before they ate the fateful fruit, they were without sin in their flesh. In other words they were perfect. As soon as disobedience came in, as soon as they sinned (entirely by their own will and not because of the weakness of their flesh) death came in. From that point on, all flesh was branded with a clock, a timebomb. From then on, the body of every human being would begin the road to death as soon as it was born. And with that timebomb came the need to keep the flesh alive and functioning, and with that necessity came a constant and irrepressible desire to follow the most humanly logical route to that end - a route that too often resulted in being disobedient to the will of God and preserving or promoting oneself at the expense of others. Adam thought he knew better than God, and all of humanity has followed the same pattern since, including you and me, every day.
To circle back around to my first quote in John 6, Jesus says, I am the bread of life. He who comes to Me shall never hunger, and he who believes in Me shall never thirst. That is still the case today, and yet our flesh, which is still earmarked for death, tries always to convince us otherwise. We, that is our souls, can be listening carefully to the instruction and commands and guidance of God through the Holy Spirit, but our flesh warns us of hunger and thirst and of what it perceives to be external threats to safety or comfort or peace. The Spirit is asking us to lay down our life for God and for one another, and the flesh is hounding us to preserve and serve ourselves at the expense of one another. And until that shouting of the flesh is permanently silenced, through death, it will never stop. And we will never be able to perfectly ignore it.
So with the bodies of death that we are born into, it is not possible for us to avoid sin.
But after we are given our bodies of glory, we will not sin anymore because we will neither 'need' to, nor will we want to. We will finally see sin with the same abhorrence that God Himself sees it, and we will no more be remotely interested in it - in fact we will be disgusted by it. Scripture says that our righteousness is as filthy rags, or to translate it more specifically, 'soiled menstrual towels'. And that perhaps helps us understand just a tiny bit how attracted we will be to sin when we have minds like Christ and bodies incorruptible.
So the only possible hope we have of resisting any one sin, is by being obedient to the will of God through the Spirit.
'But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, longsuffering, kindness, goodness, faithfulness, gentleness, self-control. Against such there is no law. And those who are Christ’s have crucified the flesh with its passions and desires. If we live in the Spirit, let us also walk in the Spirit.'
Galatians 5:22-25
'I say then: Walk in the Spirit, and you shall not fulfill the lust of the flesh. For the flesh lusts against the Spirit, and the Spirit against the flesh; and these are contrary to one another, so that you do not do the things that you wish.'
Galatians 5:16-17
I hope this helps and blesses you :)

Much wisdom in this answer but I wonder why you said "we know that the flesh is not inherently sinful because otherwise Jesus would have had sin"? In view of what you then said in para. beginning, "To wind back to A & E again..." this confuses me "all flesh was branded with a clock, a timebomb. From then on, the body of every human being would begin the road to death as soon as it was born" Surely that speaks of inherent sin from birth? And surely it was Jesus' divine nature that means we cannot compare ourselves to him when it comes to resisting sin? Only deity knows God's divine will 100%.

@Anne, thanks for your comment - the body bears the mark of death, which is a consequence of sin rather than a source of sin, if that helps to clear things up? Jesus' body aged and suffered and hungered and thirsted in no different way to us. And all of that suffering was as a consequence of sin coming into the world, not a consequence of sin being embraced by the individual.
In terms of comparing ourselves to Christ when it comes to resisting sin, we are actually encouraged to do this (Hebrews 4:14-16, 1 Corinthians 11:1, 1 Peter 2:18-25, among others)

Just a point of clarity about the Gnostic issue:
Gnosticism’s truly disgusting heresy was that all material things are inherently evil, and this led them to deny the incarnation of Christ. This is of course because if He was perfect, and all material things are evil, then He couldn’t have been material at all, only spiritual. I won’t get into the problems with this, but suffice it to say, this is a terrible heresy that fundamentally rejects the work of Christ.
That having been said, I think Paul’s discourse is most helpful to understand the flesh/spirit dichotomy:
For that which I am doing, I do not understand; for I am not practicing what I would like to do, but I am doing the very thing I hate. But if I do the very thing I do not wish to do, I agree with the Law, confessing that it is good. So now, no longer am I the one doing it, but sin which indwells me. For I know that nothing good dwells in me, that is, in my flesh; for the wishing is present in me, but the doing of the good is not. For the good that I wish, I do not do; but I practice the very evil that I do not wish. But if I am doing the very thing I do not wish, I am no longer the one doing it, but sin which dwells in me. I find then the principle that evil is present in me, the one who wishes to do good. For I joyfully concur with the law of God in the inner man, but I see a different law in the members of my body, waging war against the law of my mind, and making me a prisoner of the law of sin which is in my members. (Romans 7:15-23)
I would disagree with a commentary which suggests that “flesh” does not refer to the body, since Paul makes it expressly clear here that that’s exactly what he means by “flesh,” even saying “the members of my body.”
The Gnostic error was in saying that anything of the flesh is necessarily evil, which isn’t true. The Holy Spirit indwells our bodies (1 Cor. 1:9), and He does good works through our bodies. More importantly, Christ’s body was truly flesh but without the curse of sin, if He did not truly assume the flesh (as the Gnostics say), then He would’ve failed to fulfill the Law. Our flesh is cursed with sin, however, so we are at war with ourselves until our body dies and we receive our glorified bodies, free of sin.
I encourage you to look for references in the Pauline epistles to “flesh,” there are many other helpful passages that I think you’ll appreciate. Maybe start with the rest of Romans 7 or Galatians 5. Very dense discussion of the flesh/spirit duality.
Hope this helps, God bless you.
